# .net class serialization with backgroundworker

Tags: .net, serialization, backgroundworker

I have a class with a backgroundworker object.
When i try to serialize this class, error with the backgroundworker.

Any idea ? (please dont't tell me to remove the backgroundworker from the class)

Answer (score 0):

founded. In vb.net :

```
<Serializable>
class bob

    <NonSerialized>
    Private WithEvents _bgDo As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

end class
```

Comment: and do not forget to set <NonSerialized> to events.